# How to internalization a big app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have developped an application in Flutter. It's like a social network app with a lot of pages.. I'm wondering, how do I handle text translation? For my website, I use my database.

Many tutorials talk about json files or .arb files. but my application have hundred translations. What do you think would be the best method?

Also, the text translation should be available on all pages...
Should i use Scoped_model for that ?

What i want, is at first, detect the locale of the device, so i will select automaticly a language. but i want allow the user to change the language like Facebook did or other popular app did.

Does someone can give an advice ?

Thanks a lot !

Pascal

Comment: You can use this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/intl). Also, each text must have an ID that will help you to uniquely identify text. For reference purpose, must see this [project](https://github.com/jhomlala/feather).

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I will have a look to this library and this projet. It is important for me that the app is fast, i don't want the translation slow down the app.... Because i need to call/refresh it at every page.

Comment: you can use  [localize_and_translate](https://pub.dev/packages/localize_and_translate). it has a very good implementation included to translate and pick new language, with options to remember and restart app to apply switching